# Identification: Stinging walking/flying skin cells

Tags: species-identification, entomology, hemiptera

Here I was, sitting in the veranda, minding my own business. Kids were playing outside, and I wasn't in charge of watching them. While browsing my stack overflow feed, I felt a pinch in my left arm. Like a very tiny needle just fell from the sky and decided to 'bug' me in my free time.

I looked at the spot where it hurt and saw a minuscule insect. It looked like two shedded skin cells crawling around slowly. Just very flat and small. What surprised me is that it kept hurting for approx 30 seconds afterward.

Not knowing what it was, I decided to get the camera. But how to photograph such a tiny creature, if you do not have the proper gear. Thankfully my wife remembered a trick where you can turn around the lens of the camera (if it's detachable), and take a picture while holding the lens firmly against the body. This way you get a sort of macro. Very difficult to hold it steady and to focus, because the focus field is extremely shallow.

Nevertheless, I managed to take some shots, and now my question is.. what is this stingy little buggy? I obviously let it live after the photoshoot and most likely it's a very common insect, but I've just never seen it in my life. Especially not something that stings like that.

Ah yes, apparently it can fly. Little bugger (literally) tried to flee the scene a couple times.

Additional info:

Origin: Romania, Targoviste (DB)

Date/time: 06 July 2018, 18:30, sunset

Warm sunny but windy day, still warm, 25 degrees Celcius

[image: Grass for scale]

[image: Grass seed for scale]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is a Lace bug (Hemiptera). Family Tingidae. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tingidae.
From Wikipedia: "Lace bugs sometimes fall out of trees, land on people, and bite, which, although painful, is a minor nuisance. No medical treatment is necessary."